# Pushing non-conventional items into an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, types

I am trying to generate an arbitrary number of unconventional items into an array which would ultimately look something like this:

```
var notes = [
  new VF.StaveNote({clef: "treble", keys: ["c/5"], duration: "q" }),
  new VF.StaveNote({clef: "treble", keys: ["d/4"], duration: "q" }),
  new VF.StaveNote({clef: "treble", keys: ["b/4"], duration: "qr" }),
  new VF.StaveNote({clef: "treble", keys: ["c/4", "e/4", "g/4"], duration: "q" })
];
```

My strategy for doing so involves making a function which pushes these types into an array:

```
function makeVexFlowNotes(nonVexFlowNotes){
     var ascendingNotes = outputAscendingNotes(nonVexFlowNotes);
     var notes = [];
     for(var i=0;i<ascendingNotes.length;i++)
     {
          var temp = new VF.StaveNote({ keys: ascendingNotes[i], duration: "q" });
          notes.push(temp);
     }
     return notes;
}
```

However, my page does not render correctly when I do this.

Help is appreciated.
Thanks,
Nakul

Comment: As the error says, it's regarding VF, not adding to an array. How are you importing VF/what is VF?

Comment: You need to install `vexflow` and import it in your code first before using

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the import. That was more of a red herring. The libraries loaded in the context of my HTML document. However, the original problem of how to literally push "new VF.StaveNote({clef: "treble", keys: ["c/5"], duration: "q" })," into an array does not work still.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. You may have imported the CDN file and loaded the following code before the CDN has resolved.
2. You haven't imported `VF` at all.

Two import VF, you have to first install the package by running

```
npm install vexflow
```

and then import the module as

```
const VF = require('vexflow');

// or in es6:
import * as VF from 'vexflow';
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the import. That was more of a red herring. The libraries loaded in the context of my HTML document. However, the original problem of how to literally push "new VF.StaveNote({clef: "treble", keys: ["c/5"], duration: "q" })," into an array does not work still.

Comment: What error you're getting exactly? I need more information in order to help you